# Python command line argument semicolon-loop error

Tags: python, bash, timeit

I was trying out `python -mtimeit`so I put `python -mtimeit "n = 0; while n < 10: pass"`
Then an invalid syntax error showed up. same with semicolon and for loop.

However, when I try semicolon and loop individually. Both worked fine.

```
python -c "for i in range(10): print(n)"  
python -c "n = 1; n = 2; print(n)"
```

Why is this so and how can I test while loop in timeit? Thank you very much!

Comment: `python -mtimeit -c "n = 1; n = 2; print(n)"` ?

Comment: No need to be so apologetic!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`while`, `for` can't have semicolon before, they need to be on one line. If you looked at [Python grammar](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html):

```
compound_stmt ::=  if_stmt
                   | while_stmt
                   | for_stmt
                   | try_stmt
                   | with_stmt
                   | funcdef
                   | classdef
                   | decorated
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

you will see that the statements that are part of [`compound_stmt`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) need to be one one line alone. The only statements that can be separated by semicolon are [`simple_stmt`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-simple_stmt) group:

```
simple_stmt ::=  expression_stmt
                 | assert_stmt
                 | assignment_stmt
                 | augmented_assignment_stmt
                 | pass_stmt
                 | del_stmt
                 | print_stmt
                 | return_stmt
                 | yield_stmt
                 | raise_stmt
                 | break_stmt
                 | continue_stmt
                 | import_stmt
                 | global_stmt
                 | exec_stmt
```

Answer (score 3):

`timeit` can take two parameters:  the setup code and the code to time.

```
python -mtimeit "n = 0" "while n < 10: pass"
```

Also, you should change that `pass` to `n += 1` or you'll be in an infinite loop.

Comment: `timeit` works [fine](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface) with one argument. The issue is one of syntax.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: It's obviously not working fine with the one argument that the OP gave, while it does work with the two argument form I gave.  Good job, down-voting the only answer that actually solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve anything, because it misses the point of the question. The problem is *not* that `timeit` can *optionally* take more than one argument, or even strictly about `timeit` in the first place. The other two answers give a proper solution and an explanation of the actual problem.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: I was incorrect about being the only solution that worked -- Aleks' answer does as well.  Out of curiousity, what is "improper" about my solution to the OP's question of `how can I test while loop in timeit?`

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing it in a script, why don't you indent it just the way you would do it in a real python program? Like this:

```
python -mtimeit "
n = 0
while n < 10:
    pass"
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer superbly tackles the why, but not the question of how this can be worked around under any operating system (since windows cmd doesn't allow multi-line statements)

The answer is: exec

You have to nest any loops in an exec statement.

Examples:
(Python 2)

```
python -c "i = 3; while i:print i; i-=1"
```

is a syntax error, while

```
python -c "i = 3; exec 'while i:print i;i-=1'"
```

works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old topic but no one mentioned list comprehensions so here it is.

A list comprehension with a function could also be used, if printing is involved:

```
python2 -m timeit "from pprint import pprint; [pprint(i) for i in range(1000)]"
```

In python3 print itself would work because unlike python2 it is already a function:

```
python3 -m timeit "[print(i) for i in range(1000)]"
```